# Adjust height of NSTextFieldCell dynamically based on text

Tags: cocoa, nstableview, nstextfieldcell

Is there any way I can adjust the height of NSTextFieldCell in an NSTableView based on the amount of text in it?

In short, I want tableView:heightOfRow: to return a value according to the text in the corresponding NSTextFieldCell and keep updating every time the text increases from a pre-defined number of lines.

I can get the dynamic height the first time the table is loaded. But can't get a way of changing it when the text updates.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you'll need to call

[`[NSTableView reloadDataForRowIndexes:columnIndexes:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTableView/reloadDataForRowIndexes:columnIndexes:) for all the data underneath the cell you're modifying, and of course [`[NSTableViewDelegate tableView:heightOfRow:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSTableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSTableViewDelegate/tableView:heightOfRow:).

[This might be a helpful related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7504546/view-based-nstableview-with-rows-that-have-dynamic-heights) you can refer to.

Comment: Thanks. But this is for static content. As I said, I can get it working the first time the data loads. But when I start editing the text in the cells, I can't get the height to be adjusted according to the text.

Comment: Ewww. That sounds like a, um, interesting user interface to say the least. I can't think of any other apps off the top of my head that allow users to edit the text in an actual table view cell within a table. I'd recommend doing this in a detail view instead.

Comment: Mike this is a Mac app (NSTableView and NSTextFieldCell), not an iOS app. The whole point behind an NSTextFieldCell is allowing user to update the content right inside the table cell.

Comment: I've changed my original answer for NSTableView... but yes, I still think the UI is potentially problematic.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann - A lot of iPhone apps do this, even the Contacts and Reminder apps from Apple, and on the Mac editing in the table cell is expected.