# How to increase the row height in NSTableView based on the text Content?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstableview

How to increase the row height in a NSTableView based on the text Content.Row height should be increased when there is more text and the row should shrink when the text is deleted.

I implemented the **textDidChange** notification in my subclass of NSTableView,but I did not find any method which will increase the row height. `setRowHeight` of NSTableView will increase the height of every row in the tableview. I would like to a variable row height.Can I have any sample code or any pointers to accomplish this.

---

I found the following link

http://cocoadev.com/forums/discussion/1851/calculating-row-heights

But I am not able to find any example on this!. Any example on this would be a great help for me!

---

Tried to implement the following deleagate

`- (CGFloat)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView heightOfRow:(NSInteger)row`

by calculating the string length,Now I am able to increase the row height ,but the **NSTextFieldCell**  height is same.  How can I increase the height of the textfield when the row height changes.

Answer (score 1):

corbin dunn [gave a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8054170/1460929):

- fix your autoresizing/AutoLayout coinstraints so the text view sticks to its container,
- calculate the row height `-tableView:heightOfRow:` with the help of a custom NSTableCellView 
  object.

Answer (score -9):

You can increase height of tableviewrow in the method `- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {}` . Call `[tableView reloadData]` in `textDidFinishEditing` to reload the table .

Comment: Caution : the question was about `NSTableView`, this answer is about `UITableView`. Cocoa ≠ Cocoa Touch.