# Correctly resizing rows on view-based NSTableView

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstableview, appkit

A view-based `NSTableView` with rows that have dynamic heights doesn't resize its rows when the table view size is changed. This is a problem when the row height is derived from the table view's width (think text blocks that fills a column and wraps thus extending the row size).

I've been trying to get `NSTableView` to resize its rows whenever it changed size but have experienced little success:

- If I resize only the visible rows by querying `enumerateAvailableRowViewsUsingBlock:`, some of the non-visible rows doesn't get resized and thus were shown with the old height when the user scrolls and reveal these rows.
- If I resize all rows it becomes noticeably slow when there are a lot of rows (about 1 second delay after each window resize for 1000 rows in my 1.8Ghz i7 MacBook Air).

Anybody can help?

This is where I detect the table view size change - in the table view's delegate:

```c
- (void)tableViewColumnDidResize:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    NSTableView* aTableView = aNotification.object;
    if (aTableView == self.messagesView) {
        // coalesce all column resize notifications into one -- calls messagesViewDidResize: below

        NSNotification* repostNotification = [NSNotification notificationWithName:BSMessageViewDidResizeNotification object:self];
        [[NSNotificationQueue defaultQueue] enqueueNotification:repostNotification postingStyle:NSPostWhenIdle];
    }
}
```

Whereas the following is the handler of the notification posted above, where the visible rows get resized:

```c
-(void)messagesViewDidResize:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSTableView* messagesView = self.messagesView;

    NSMutableIndexSet* visibleIndexes = [NSMutableIndexSet new];
    [messagesView enumerateAvailableRowViewsUsingBlock:^(NSTableRowView *rowView, NSInteger row) {
        if (row >= 0) {
            [visibleIndexes addIndex:row];
        }
    }];
    [messagesView noteHeightOfRowsWithIndexesChanged:visibleIndexes];   
}
```

The alternative implementation that resizes all rows looks like this:

```c
-(void)messagesViewDidResize:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSTableView* messagesView = self.messagesView;      
    NSIndexSet indexes = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(0,messagesView.numberOfRows)];      
    [messagesView noteHeightOfRowsWithIndexesChanged:indexes];  
}
```

Note: This question is somewhat related to [View-based NSTableView with rows that have dynamic heights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7504546/view-based-nstableview-with-rows-that-have-dynamic-heights) but is more focused towards responding to the table view's size change.

Answer (score 12):

I just went through this exact problem. What I did was monitor the NSViewBoundsDidChangeNotification for the scroll view's content view

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(scrollViewContentBoundsDidChange:) name:NSViewBoundsDidChangeNotification object:self.scrollView.contentView];
```

and in the handler, get the visible rows and call noteHeightOfRowsWithIndexesChange:.  I disable animation while doing this so the user doesn't see the rows wiggle during the resize as view's come into the table

```
- (void)scrollViewContentBoundsDidChange:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    NSRange visibleRows = [self.tableView rowsInRect:self.scrollView.contentView.bounds];
    [NSAnimationContext beginGrouping];
    [[NSAnimationContext currentContext] setDuration:0];
    [self.tableView noteHeightOfRowsWithIndexesChanged:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:visibleRows]];
    [NSAnimationContext endGrouping];
}
```

This has to perform quickly so the table scrolls nicely but its working very well for me.

Comment: For me I waited till the user have completed resizing then re-adjust the row heights.

Comment: apparently the scroll view content view doesn't post change notifications, even after calling `[self.scrollView.contentView setPostsBoundsChangedNotifications:YES]`

Comment: it seems that NSViewFrameDidChangNotification works better for live resizing

Comment: +1 for NSViewFrameDidChangNotification, although it's actually spelled `NSViewFrameDidChangeNotification`, which I quickly found out after Xcode cried at me!

Comment: Thanks a ton bro swift code is follows                                                      let column = notification.userInfo?["NSTableColumn"] as? NSTableColumn
        if let tableView = column?.tableView {
              print("_____TEST2222222")
            let visibleRowRange = tableView.rowsInRect(tableView.visibleRect)
            
            NSAnimationContext.beginGrouping()
            NSAnimationContext.currentContext().duration = 0
            tableView.noteHeightOfRowsWithIndexesChanged(NSIndexSet(indexesInRange: visibleRowRange))
             NSAnimationContext.endGrouping()

Comment: Thanks for the swift! I'm just starting a new mac app and trying to remember all this errata that I discovered back then and how to do it all in swift!