# Mavericks issue: noteHeightOfRowsWithIndexesChanged: does not animate

Tags: objective-c, animation, nstableview, osx-mavericks

When calling `[myTableView noteHeightOfRowsWithIndexesChanged: myIndexSet]` inside an     `NSAnimationContext` group, the height of the rows animates on 10.8, but does not animate on 10.9: it jumps instantaneously to the final height instead.

After some experimentation, I found that it does animate on 10.9 if you do not place that call to the table view in an `NSAnimationContext` group.

This result is a bummer because I wanted to have other animations on the rows in sync with the height animation from the table view. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried anything like allowsImplicitAnimations?

Comment: @uchuugaka I've just tried it and it works! Fascinating, I'd never have called that one. You can rewrite your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try setAllowsImplicitAnimations: YES

For performance or legacy reasons some AppKit interface objects might not set that as a default. The tricky part is that bit about inheritance. 
Many things have important parts that are inherited but not always documented clearly in the immediate object docs. 
This is where some things are in AppKit release notes or only in WWDC videos.