# How to automatically set row height in NSOutlineView to fit text?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, autolayout, nstableview, nsoutlineview

TLDR: I want to implement the method of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7504546/view-based-nstableview-with-rows-that-have-dynamic-heights) (or any other relevant method) on a `NSOutlineView`.

A `NSOutlineView` is more complicated than a `NSTableView` because some cells may be indented with respect to others, due to parent/child relationships.

I am open to using any method, including AutoLayout if that is possible.  My views are simple `NSTableCellView` instances with only a `NSTextField`.

---

I need to be able to set the height of a row in a view-based `NSOutlineView` depending on the text in that row's `NSTextField`.

I am currently using the following (simplified) code, which makes use of [`NSString+Geometics`](http://www.sheepsystems.com/sourceCode/sourceStringGeometrics.html) to calculate the approximate height of the view given its width:

```
- (CGFloat)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView
     heightOfRowByItem:(id)item
{
    static NSTableCellView *cell;

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [self.outlineView makeViewWithIdentifier:@"Cell"
                                                  owner:self];
    }

    NSString *text = [item text];
    float width = cell.textField.bounds.size.width;
#warning this is completely wrong due to different levels of indentation

    float height = [text heightForWidth:width];

    return height;
}
```

The idea behind this code is to keep a scratch cell around in order to make use of its default bounds property.  This works correctly for the top level row.

However, any 'child' (nested) rows in the `NSOutlineView` are indented towards the right.  To calculate the required height of the `NSTextField` correctly, I need to know the width of the `NSTextField` after this indentation.

How can I obtain this information?

---

I should note that it is not possible to call

```
[outlineView viewAtColumn:0
                      row:[outlineView rowForItem:item]
          makeIfNecessary:YES]
```

from within `outlineView:heightOfRowByItem:`, which means that you can't get a reference to the current cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `-[NSOutlineView indentationPerLevel]` to calculate reduced child width.

Comment: Thanks!  I have no idea how I missed that property, but it was exactly what I was after.