# Dynamic TableviewCell heights in Cocoa (Mac)

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstableview, nstablecellview

I am trying to archive a similar behavior to what the Twitter for Mac App has.
It has TableViewCells of dynamic height that properly resize if the user resizes the whole window.

I started using an NSTableView with view based TableViewCells.
Now my problem is that I can calculate the initial height of a TableViewCell, but as soon as the user starts resizing the whole window, the height of course isn't correct any more and the tableview is't asking me again for a new height...

So my question is how I can solve this problem? Are TableViews the way to go?
I'd love it to work with AutoLayout somehow...

Thanks,
Georg

Comment: possible duplicate of [View-based NSTableView with rows that have dynamic heights](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7504546/view-based-nstableview-with-rows-that-have-dynamic-heights)

Comment: The important part for me is that the rows need to resize if I resize the window. Without any lag and smoothly... From my first look at the link this doesn't seem to be handled

Comment: __the tableview is't asking me again for a new height__ It asks for height only when you do a reload. So on window resize calculate height and reload...

Comment: but is that a proper clean solution? Or are there better UI-Elements than a TableView for such things?