# View based NSTableView and row heights

Tags: macos, swift, cocoa

I'm beginning to try and build an OSX app.

I'm using NSTableView with it set as view-based, however I want the rows to wrap properly (so all of the text in each is shown at once) however I can't seem to find out how do to this.

Using the `rowHeight` delegate method seems to point to cell-based NSTableViews so I don't know if I'm doing that right or not.

Comment: Have you read this post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7504546/view-based-nstableview-with-rows-that-have-dynamic-heights

Comment: @renfei Yes, I'll try and read over it again but I didn't understand it :/ I'm really new to OSX development

Answer (score 1):

First select NSTableView and then Size Inspector and set row height:
[image]

and then select table cell view's which you want change:
[image]

And if you want then you can move or resize your table view cell if you want.

Comment: Thanks, I'm sorry I didn't make my question very clear but I'm wanting the rows to be different sizes so that the text will wrap around nicely

Comment: Ok, sorry I can't help you for that :(