# How to update row heights of NSTableView with usesAutomaticRowHeights = true after column resize?

Tags: macos, autolayout, nstableview

Since macOS 10.13 we can use NSTableView with automatic row heights, thanks to the new property `usesAutomaticRowHeights` and of course auto layout. This works quite nicely.

But when the user resizes a column, the calculated heights are no longer correct, and gaps appear in the tableview cells.

Is there a proven way to update the row heights after column resize in this scenario?

I already tried methods like `updateConstraintsForSubtreeIfNeeded()`, `updateConstraints()`, `setNeedsDisplay()`, `reloadData()` and so on, but nothing works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use NSTextField's in your design, make sure the `Desired Width` setting of each NSTextField with dynamic height, is set to `Automatic`. This setting is located in the Size Inspector.

Changing this resulted in automatic recalculation of the tableview row heights.

Answer (score 3):

Something that worked for me was to include the `tableViewColumnDidResize` notification method in the NSTableviewDelegate. There you can call the `noteHeightOfRows` method of the table view. Here is an implementation:

```
   //Recalculate when the screen moves
   func tableViewColumnDidResize(_ notification: Notification) {
     let allIndex = IndexSet(integersIn:0..<self.YOURTABLE.numberOfRows)
    YOURTABLE.noteHeightOfRows(withIndexesChanged: allIndex)
}
```

Here are the links to the documentation: [tableViewColumnDidResize](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstableviewdelegate/1535901-tableviewcolumndidresize) and [noteHeightOfRows](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstableview/1532126-noteheightofrows)

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately this doesn't work in my code. Do you use `usesAutomaticRowHeights = true`?

Comment: I have set the Row Size style to "Automatic (auto layout)" through Interface Builder. When you say it doesn´t work, do you mean it doesn´t get called or that it does nothing when being called?

Comment: it does get called, but the height of the rows remain the same. All my other attempts were also in the same tableViewColumnDidResize delegate. Did you also implement the `heightOfRow` delegate? If true, remains your code working when your remove this delegate?

Comment: Yes, I also have `HeightOfRow` implemented and it does not work if I remove this. What I´m doing there is creating and configuring the view and calling `layoutSubtreeIfNeeded`. After that, I return the height of the view.

Comment: OK, but then your are not really using the new automatic row heights feature. My code works without the `heightOfRow` delegate.

Comment: @Ely I was able to make it work without `heightOfRow ` or `tableViewColumnDidResize`, I followed [https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/AppKit/RN-AppKit/#10_13NSTableView%20Automatic%20Row%20Heights] and made sure the layout constraints, hugging and compression were adequate