# How to fill the text color and set auto cell size like zoom chat for macOS

Tags: swift, macos, nstextfield, nstableviewcell

I have implemented custom NSTableCellView and made the layout like this image but the issue here is

I have implemented full width NSTextField,

How to make automatic tablecellview height based on the chat text size

like in iOS we use

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44
```

attaching the sample layout image of Zoom Chat for reference I am looking for
[[image: Zoom Chat1]

Comment: "I have implemented custom NSTableViewCell"  `NSTableCellView`, you mean?

Comment: Ask one question at a time.

Comment: @ElTomato I have corrected the question as per your comments.  Thank You

Comment: I see.  I have never considered doing that.  I'll take a look later on.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [View-based NSTableView with rows that have dynamic heights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7504546/view-based-nstableview-with-rows-that-have-dynamic-heights)